# Invert color of specific window or portion of the screen on mac os x

Tags: macos, mac

When coding, I have a dark theme on my text editor. However the browser window is bright white (eg. the web app I'm coding and the dev tools in chrome) and it's not very comfortable for the eyes to switch between the browser window and the text editor which I've placed next to each other on a 27-inch screen.

Does anybody know about a software that only inverts the screen colors for a specific app or just for a portion of the screen? (ie. I donnot want to invert the colors of the entire screen)

**Update:** for chrome specifically:

- There is now a dark theme for their dev tools: http://thenextweb.com/insider/2016/02/10/google-chromes-developer-tools-are-finally-getting-a-dark-theme/#gref
- And there are a few extension to invert the colors, the one I use is called hacker vision: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hacker-vision/fommidcneendjonelhhhkmoekeicedej

Comment: It sounds like [Nocturne](https://code.google.com/p/blacktree-nocturne/) might be what you're looking for, but there appear to be a couple of problems running it with Mavericks according to the issues list.